# Validating data in Orbeon XBL component

Tags: orbeon

I want to create a custom XBL component for Orbeon Form Builder that would contain an input text and validate it.

I've managed to create the component and add it to the Form Builder sidebar, but I can't figure out how to do the validation.

The validation I'm looking to do is kind of complex, it's similar to a credit card, some digits have special significance and then there's a checksum that needs to be computed and validated.

What I have so far is this:

```
<xbl:xbl xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
         xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         xmlns:my="http://example.com/xbl">

    <xbl:binding element="my|component" id="my-component" xxbl:mode="lhha binding value">
        <metadata xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
            <display-name lang="en">Component</display-name>
            <icon lang="en">
                <small-icon>/forms/orbeon/builder/images/input.png</small-icon>
                <large-icon>/forms/orbeon/builder/images/input.png</large-icon>
            </icon>
            <templates>
                <view>
                    <xf:input id="" ref="" xmlns="">
                        <xf:label ref=""/>
                        <xf:hint ref=""/>
                        <xf:help ref=""/>
                        <xf:alert ref=""/>
                    </xf:input>
                </view>
            </templates>
        </metadata>
    </xbl:binding>
</xbl:xbl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a validation template in the metadata, at the same level as `<view>`, but using `<bind>`. For example:

```
<bind
    type="xf:integer"
    constraint="...some XPath expression here..."/>
```

You could omit the `xf:integer` type if the value is otherwise validated by the `constraint`.

With `constraint`, you should be able to validate your checksum.

If part of your value follows the same rules as credit cards, you could use the standard [`is-card-number()`](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XPath_Expressions_Module#The_is-card-number.28.29_Function) function as a helper.

Comment: The credit card was just an example, it's different, but still implies that some digits be in some ranges and calculating a checksum on the whole string.
Can you kindly point to a documentation with the functions available and maybe some examples?
I tried adding the bind, but it seems to do nothing, it's not even in the form XML after I add the component.

Comment: The functions comprise [standard functions](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/standard-functions), as well as [extension functions](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions).

Comment: I would start trying to write the validation outside the component. Then we can see why it doesn't seem to apply when placed in the component's `bind` template.

Comment: Can I include multiple constraints, each with it's own error message?

Comment: Right now, the code only looks at attributes on the bind template so it's not possible to insert more than one. Added [RFE #3728](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3728).